# Van der Waerden theorem generalization

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k\geq 3$ be an integer. I want to show that if $N_0$ is sufficiently large then for any coloring $c:\{1,...,2N\}\to\{0,1\}$ with $N\geq N_0$ and $|c^{-1}(0)|=|c^{-1}(1)|=N$ the sets $c^{-1}(0)$ and $c^{-1}(1)$ contain $k$-term arithmetic progressions with the same common difference.

**Attempt:** I thought about using Van der Waerden's theorem. There is some $N_1$ such that every $2$-coloring of $\{1,...,N\}$ for $N\geq N_0$ contains a monochromatic $k$-term arithmetic progression. I thought about taking $N_0$ to be something like $N_1^2$, then given a $2$-coloring of $\{1,...,2N\}$ with $N\geq N_0$ and each color being used $N$ times we can take all $N_1$-term arithmetic progressions in $\{1,...,2N\}$, there are lots of them. Each one of them contains a monochromatic $k$-term arithmetic progression by Van der Waerden's theorem. However, I don't see how to continue. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a proof using Szemerédi's theorem.  In fact we prove that if $k\in \mathbb N$ and $\delta>0$, there is an $N=N(k,\delta)$ such that if $A, B\subset [1,N]$ with $|A|=|B|>\delta N$, then $A$ and $B$ contain $k$-term APs of the same common difference.  The key is to find a translate $A+t$ of $A$ so that $|(A+t)\cap B|> \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 N$, then apply Szemerédi's theorem to $(A+t)\cap B$.   To find such $t$, note that $|A||B| = \sum_{t=-N+1}^N |(A+t)\cap B|$: the sum counts each element of $B$  $|A|$ times.  Thus one summand is at least $\frac{1}{2N}|A||B|>\frac{1}{2}\delta^2 N$.

Comment: @John Griesmer This is a very nice way to prove it. Thanks a lot. I probably tried to solve this problem way too early, it took time before I learned about Szemeredi's theorem. You might write it as an answer, and I will accept it then.